# How to make slider move by pressing up and down arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, frontend

Hi i was trying to make this slider move by pressing up and down arrow, i tried this code but it's not working properly

JsFiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/babuharry/83h6wb5s/)

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 38) { // top
    $(".swiper-slide").animate({
      top: "-=518"
    });
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 40) { // bottom
    $(".swiper-slide").animate({
      bottom: "+=518"
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Share the HTML code please

Comment: hi @Michael have a look Jsfiddle

Comment: @babuharry Please post the full code in the question itself. Questions need to be self contained as if an external link fails the question will lose its context.

Comment: am sorry, i will do it from next time sure, and thanks for your time the question is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swiper library you are using has a method to go to the next and previous slide (you can see the whole API documentation of this library here: http://idangero.us/swiper/api/)

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  direction: "vertical",
  loop: false,
  pagination: ".swiper-pagination",
  grabCursor: true,
  speed: 1000,
  paginationClickable: true,
  parallax: true,
  autoplay: false,
  effect: "slide",
  mousewheelControl: 1
});

$("body").keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 38) { // top
    mySwiper.slidePrev();
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 40) { // bottom
    mySwiper.slideNext();
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h1atwcyy/

Answer (score 2):

Why not just `trigger the click` action and let the keyboard do the same the mouse click would do..

```
$("body").keydown(function(e) {

  if(e.keyCode == 38) { // top
    $('.swiper-pagination-bullet-active').prev().trigger('click');
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 40) { // bottom
    $('.swiper-pagination-bullet-active').next().trigger('click');
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/83h6wb5s/5/

Comment: Wow it's working, sir can you explain me how did it work in simple words

Comment: @babuharry if you use the keyboard up/down arrown it just looks for the swiper active link and fires a click event on the next or previous element. So it's like you would click on the element. Nothing else to do

Comment: yea i see that, but i din't pay attention again, i got it now thanks a lot have a great time